# Check if user is authorized inside Action (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There is user log in on home page in modal window using ajax (it uses method `LogIn` from `User` Controller)

```
[HttpPost]
[AjaxAction]
public ActionResult LogIn(UserModel user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (IsValid(user.Email, user.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);                 

            return Json(new { status = "OK", message = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }               
    }

    return Json(new { status = "ERROR", message = "Data is incorrect" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and if log in was successful, I do redirect on `Task/Index` page.
I would like to add check in `Index` action of `Home` Controller, if user already is authorized, redirect him to `Task/Index`, otherwise to show `Index` view of `Home` Controller.

I tried code below

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)                
        {
            return Redirect("/Task/Index");

        }
        return View();

    }
}
```

but redirect works in any case. How to fix it?

Comment: When you say redirect works in any case, so the `IsAuthenticated` property is always true even when it's a completely new session?

Comment: If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true means that your user is logged in, you have to log out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)                
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Task");
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```